# How to select two column merge lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to connect to database and database table select merge the two column.And this column return this query should return the records I selected.
For Example;

**Connection information**

*columns is:*

Address City

**Table Name:** Address

Address: 2
City: B

I want to result:

Address+City:2B

**Connection information2**

*columns is:*

Address City

**Table Name:** Address

Address: 3
City: C

I want to result:

Address+City:3C

if 3c is entered, the value is 3c and I want to add it if it is in the 2nd database.

I'm connecting to two databases. I'm going to add the address city in which database it exists. So how do I get this with select.

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnectınformation);
    GetTables().Address.Select(o => new Model { Address = o.Address, City = o.City });


SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnectınformation2);
GetTables().Address.Select(t => new Model { Address = t.Address, City = t.City });

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnectınformation);
GetTables().Address.Select(o => new Model { Address = o.Address, City = o.City });


SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnectınformation2);
GetTables().Address.Select(t => new Model { Address = t.Address, City = t.City });
```

Not error but not merge the select database table.

Comment: GetTables().Address.Select(t => new Model { Address = t.Address+t.City }); Please make clear about "I want to add it if it is in the 2nd database.

"

Comment: @MoinulIslam I just want to select to combined value of the entered value.If select after insert connection database.

Comment: Then try the code of the first comment. you can GetTables().Address.Select(t => new  { Address = t.Address+t.City });